# Does Elastic Topbeats show process arguments

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Elastic (Elasticsearch) Topbeat looks very interesting.  But, if I have a host with several processes all the same binary, ie. java, python, etc..  they can only be identified by looking at the subsequent command line arguments.

I've just started to deploy this.  But I can't find in the config definition option for 'long' form of process list.

Answer (score 1):

This feature should have been added in Topbeat 1.2.0: https://github.com/elastic/topbeat/pull/63.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei. That's great news.